# Parse date with %o ISO-8601 year format

Tags: php, date, iso8601

Short story: the guy that originally wrote this code was [and probably still is] pants-on-head retarded.

The code in question receives payment events from our provider and logs them into the database with the format: `'o-m-d H:i:s'`

This is all well and good, except the `%o` modifier will give you a different year if the ISO-8601 week "belongs" to a different year. [[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)]

Case in point: we have payments logged for 2013-12-31 which, in normal/not-crazy-person date, should be 2012-12-31. So for all intents and purposes we see what appear to be payments happening in the future, and occasionally in the past.

The *real* problem here is that I cannot find any date parsing function in PHP or mySQL that will interpret the `%o` flag, thus preventing me from re-formatting these dates back into something sane.

Does anyone know how to get these dates interpreted properly?

Comment: the 2012-12-31 is a Monday. Due to the rule (last thursday), this is the 1st week of 2013. So `o-m-d` will give you `2013-12-31` which is formally right. But you mixed ISO 8601 formatters with "standard" formatters. Why aren't you either using `c`as a full format for ISO 8601 or just `Y-m-d`ehich will give you 2012-12-31?

Comment: @AxelAmthor because the guy that originally wrote this was a complete moron. I don't know what would possess anyone to ever do this, but there are 'o-m-d' formats *everywhere*. Shockingly, he was fired for incompetence.

Comment: **Does anyone know how to get these dates interpreted properly?** - actually they ARE interpreted formally proper. You need to change your code.

Comment: @AxelAmthor Yes, they are *written* in a "proper" format, but then problem is that I cannot make PHP *read* it back in in the same format so that I can add/subtract date intervals. These `o-m-d` formats are *everywhere* in this code, and there are already thousands of database records written with this format that I need to work with. Even if I *could* just "change the code" I'd still need to be a able to read in and re-write the dates from `o-m-d` to `Y-m-d` and PHP doesn't have a function that will read it. This is the entire point of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, nothing I know of. However, doing a grep for all your files for `o-m-d`, which is a rather unique term, should solve you 98% of your problems through the entire codebase.

If you're using a VCS (and since you sound like a sane person, you probably are), make a commit, grep (or super-search-and-replace), and see if it works better for you, if it does, commit, if not, discard. It's really as simple as that.

If that doesn't work for you... Well... May God have mercy upon your soul.